# Microsoft Graph refresh token expiry

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Just a quick question to make sure I understand MS graph's refresh token expiry:

- If a refresh token is expired (for instance, in some configs after 90 days), is there any way to still get a new refresh token? If not, should the permissions for the apps be configured anew (in other words, should a new connection with MS be made and approved by either user or admin?)

Comment: Hi and thanks for your answer. I does not entirely solve my issue. The key point is that a token that is expired with a refresh token that is expired can no longer be used and a new token needs to be generated.

Answer (score 1):

MS graph's is not responsible for the refresh token. The authentication process is handled by Azure AD So, Microsoft Graph simply accepts the tokens Azure AD issues.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. But it doesn't fully answer my question. Can you elaborate? Sorry if I don't understand.

Comment: You need to pass the refresh before expire then you will get new access and [refresh token](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749#section-2.1)